# How to display text in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have some functions and some variables. I would like to return a variable and the function outcome as text on my browser.

What I have done is I have made a HTML file with the text:

```
<SCRIPT SRC="rockpaper.js">
</SCRIPT>
```

And this refers to this javascript file:

```
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
var computerChoice = Math.random();
if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
    computerChoice = "Computer chooses rock";
} else if(computerChoice <= 0.67) {
    computerChoice = "Computer chooses paper";
} else {
    computerChoice = "Computer chooses scissors";
}

console.log(computerChoice);

var compare = function(choice1,choice2)
{
    if(choice1===choice2)
    {
        return("The result is a tie!");
    }

    if(choice1==="Computer chooses rock")
    {
        if(choice2==="scissors")
        {
            return("rock wins");
        }
            else
            {
                return("paper wins");
            }
    }
    if(choice1==="Computer chooses paper")
    {
        if(choice2==="rock")
            return("paper wins");
            else
            {
                return("scissors wins");
            }
    }
    if(choice1==="Computer chooses scissors")
    {
        if(choice2==="rock")
        {
        return("rock wins");
        }
        else
        {
            return("scissors wins");
        }
    }
}

console.log(compare(computerChoice,userChoice))
```

However, when I open it with a browser, the text doesn't display, but the prompt does.

It works fine in Codecademy, though.

Comment: Have you opened up your browser console? The text should be displayed there. In case you are using Google Chrome, look for the console in Tools / Developer tools.

Comment: console.log() outputs to your browser console (hit f12 to bring it up).  If you want to display the text to a browser window, you need to assign the return value to a var, then do document.write(var);

Comment: How would I assign the return value to a var? Thank you.

Comment: @BjarniJóhannsson if you do not know what a var is or how to use it then maybe you're starting to learn javascript in the wrong place.

Comment: I almost got it. Using document.write() I have gotten my two sentences together in the browser, but they are written directly after each other. How do I add an indent between them? (like if I pressed enter, not sure what it's called).

Comment: @BjarniJóhannsson take a look at this http://jsfiddle.net/QXb6M/1 forget `document.write();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing being displayed on the page is normal behaviour seeing as you have not told the browser to do so.

Maybe you want something like this.

```
document.body.innerHTML = compare(computerChoice, userChoice);
```

Basically, this set's the HTML of the body to value and removes anything currently in the body, or

```
var generatedText = compare(computerChoice,userChoice), // 1
    myText = document.createTextNode( generatedText );  // 2
document.body.appendChild( myText );                    // 3
```

Will on line **1** get the generated value and save it, on line **2** will create a text element on the document and on line **3** it will append the text element/node to the end of the body.

This way nothing is removed from the document.

Comment: Thank you. I will try these. Could you please explain these properties briefly?

Comment: None of these properties seem to add the text to the webpage itself. I simply copy pasted them and put them at the end of my .js code.

Comment: @BjarniJóhannsson read up on the properties, they are the most common ways to insert html into the document.

Comment: Line // 2 above has the keyword **var** missing from the beginning, it should say:
`var myText = document.createTextNode( generatedText );  // 2`